# Angular Material <mat-select> - execute function on blur

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a `<mat-select>` element and I want to execute a function on blur of the element.

currently the function executes on selection change:

```
<mat-form-field fxFlex>
  <mat-label>SSR Status</mat-label>
  <mat-select [formControl]="ssrStatuses" multiple (selectionChange)="filtersUpdated()" [(value)]="selectedSsrStatuses">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let ssrStatus of ssrStatusList" [value]="ssrStatus.id">{{ssrStatus.label}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

I can't see any mention of blur or focus in the angular material mat-select docs. [These docs](https://coursetro.com/posts/code/59/Angular-4-Event-Binding) on angular 4 mention `(blur)="myMethod()"` but that doesn't work on my `<mat-select>`. How do I execute a function on blur of `<mat-select>`?

Answer (score 10):

If it is still actual, try to use `closed` event:

```
<mat-select (closed)="someMethod()">
  <mat-option></mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Many native [DOM events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events) works with Angular. In fact, you should have test blur event you find in Angular 4 docs because it works

```
// some html    
<h4>Basic native select</h4>
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Cars</mat-label>
      <select (blur)="blurred()" matNativeControl required>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      </select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Basic blurred method :

```
// some component.ts
blurred() {
    console.log('blurred !')
  }
```

[Bonus, stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gtc9hx?file=app/select-overview-example.ts) :

Comment: It doesn't work. It calls the function even when selection changed, and it even breaks that, calling the function with only the old options selected, not the last option selected.

Comment: You're not even using the same component as the question is about. Neither is that example.

Comment: If your element lose focus, no matter what, the blur events is triggered so it's normal to me. Maybe you should clarify what you want to do exactly, maybe you need another events but blur...

Comment: `How do I execute a function on blur of <mat-select>?`, that was your original question. I provided an example, you can adapt it to your need. You can also clarify what you really need so I can adapt my answer

Comment: You haven't provided an example. I'm using `mat-select`. It fires a function on blur, but it also fired it on selection change, when I use `(blur)="blurred()"`

Comment: (blur) = "onBlur(event$)"  works for me, however....  neither calling  onChanged() or onTouched successfully triggers the FormGroups changed() event.   So... I still have ops larger issue of not being able to wire a customComponent to a FormGroup that is configured for onBlur